# Angular How launch index.html without any httpserver

Tags: html, angular

I need to start dist/index.html directly using browser without any http server. 
when I open dist/index.html I got those errors :
**Loading failed for the  with source “file:///inline.318b50c57b4eba3d437b.bundle.js”.**
**Loading failed for the  with source “file:///polyfills.23490afe3349284ca349.bundle.js”.**

Comment: is it possible with other js frameworks? (react or vue..)

Comment: Sorry I may have been wrong. Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40024994/1350162

Comment: in index.html <base href="Your dist folder path" />

Comment: after changing base href, I can see first page , but I got this error : ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): SecurityError: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'file:///home/maoodb/Documents/mean-docker/angular-client/dist/' cannot be created in a document with origin 'null' and URL 'file:///home/maoodb/Documents/mean-docker/angular-client/dist/index.html'.