# Run Angular 7 project locally on file:/// without server

Tags: angular, routes, angular7

I want to build my angular project and generate a ZIP file containing it to send it via email and I want the person who receives it to be able to open it on his Desktop clicking index.html file.

I changed the baseUrl to ./ or to document.location but I'm getting the following error: "Unhandled Navigation Error"

Does anyone have any hint about how to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run Angular2 as static app in browser without a server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40024147/run-angular2-as-static-app-in-browser-without-a-server)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can run angular app on double click on index.html file. Just add below code in your app.module.ts

note that :  remove  `baseUrl = ./` from index.html file

```js
//in App.module.ts : 

//import these packages  

import { APP_BASE_HREF, LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';


// add these packages into providers as below : 

@NgModule({
    imports: 
     [
      .....
     ],
    declarations: 
     [
     ....
     ],
    providers: 
      [
        ....
        { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' },
        { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy },
        
        ....
       ]
   ....
   
   })
   
   export class Appmodule{}
```

Now execute  :  `npm run build` and double click the `index.html` file from `dist` folder.
You app should run.

Comment: @user10899511 can produce sample stackblitz , what have you  tries so far

Comment: I was missing to remove the <base> element from index.html, I did that and it's working!

Comment: @user10899511 glad that it worked!... please accept the answer :)

Comment: mate, any chance to use router in this `index.html` mode?

Comment: Thanks it worked with little changes for Angular 8 which I have posted in answer.

Answer (score 8):

This is what I have done for Angular 8.

After following the steps provided by @programoholic go to ./dist/index.html and remove type="module" attribute from all of the script tags.

Below is my working index.html file

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>StartApp</title>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script src="runtime-es2015.js"></script>
  <script src="runtime-es5.js" nomodule defer></script>
  <script src="polyfills-es5.js" nomodule defer></script>
  <script src="polyfills-es2015.js"></script>
  <script src="styles-es2015.js"></script>
  <script src="styles-es5.js" nomodule defer></script>
  <script src="vendor-es2015.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor-es5.js" nomodule defer></script>
  <script src="main-es2015.js"></script>
  <script src="main-es5.js" nomodule defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 6):

In Angular 9 (not sure about versions between Angular 2 - 9, should work the same), you don't need to change the `LocationStrategy` to render the **index.html** from the `dist/` directory.

Instead, you have to just specify the `base url` as `./` to make it accessible as a file path.

1. Run an `ng build --prod --base-href ./` in the app route directory and generate the `dist/` files
2. Then, like @zaki-mohammed has stated, remove the `type="module"` from the `script`s. I removed the `nomodule defer` too

   **Ex:**

   ```
   <script src="runtime-es2015.1eba213af0b233498d9d.js" type="module"></script>
   <script src="runtime-es5.1eba213af0b233498d9d.js" nomodule defer></script>
   ```

   should be changed to,

   ```
   <script src="runtime-es2015.1eba213af0b233498d9d.js"></script>
   <script src="runtime-es5.1eba213af0b233498d9d.js"></script>
   ```

Now the **index.html** file should render in a browser.

Also follow, https://stackoverflow.com/a/61220058/4294275

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @programoholic's answere. If you don't want to remove `<base>` element manually from `index.html` you can build using this:

```
ng build --base-href= --prod
```