# How to use Angular in Laravel

Tags: php, angular, laravel

I am working Laravel 7 and Angular 10 separately. but in My new project I am going to working with both Laravel and Angular. I need install Angular to My Laravel and do My Javascript task using Angular. but I have following problems to solve

1.could I install Angular in my Laravel app?
2.Than, How (using npm)
3.could I use Angular to do java script task in the laravel app like (Vue.js)

Comment: You can't use angular in laravel, because angular is a whole giant framework, But react and vue are libraries that can run anywhere. if you really want to work with angular then you can use `angularjs`

Comment: There is some valuable feedback from the SO community here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40024147/run-angular2-as-static-app-in-browser-without-a-server

Answer (score -1):

This tutorial may help you regarding using angular with laravel.
https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/10/23/php-laravel-angular-crud-app

Comment: The link describes how to do it separately